# Why is 15 + 15 different from 15 * 2?

Tags: multiplicative-function

(Apologies if the tag is incorrect. I can't find a "Multiplication" tag or similar)

I'm going to be adding a set of 5 numbers up and dividing them to get the average for a java game I am making.

However, there seems to be something wrong with it. I would have thought 15 + 15 / 2 would have been 15, however that seems incorrect.

[image]

However, 15 * 2 / 2 yields the expected result.

[image]

What is the difference here? Will doing counting up the variables and dividing them by the amount of variables work correctly in my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably write $(15+15)/2$ with parentheses and this will yield $15$.

Note that $22.5$ is $15+(15/2)$. In fact Google shows you that this is what it is calculating (taking into account the conventional order of operations).

Comment: Oh dammit. Of course it is. Because I use Java, I am not used to that sort of behaviour.

Comment: @user2722083 Java has exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: @AlexR Java does things in the order you typed them. This means that if I did (15 + 15 / 2), it would do 15 + 15, then divide that by 2. In C++, if I did the same, then it would do the same as google has done.

Comment: @user2722083 Nope. Try it out and see. Every meaningful programming language respects this so-called "precedence" order.

Comment: @user2722083 Certainly not, check [the docs](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). Actually, I doubt that *any* programming language with arithmetic expressions exhibits this confusing behaviour.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Wow. Looks like I've been living with that misconception for at least 3 years.

Comment: @user2722083 It's about time to revisti your last three years worth of code ;)

Answer (score 2):

Order of Operations: Division comes before addition. So when you input 15+15/2 you get 15+7.5. To get the answer you want input (15+15)/2.

Comment: I think you mean  "before addition"

Comment: Yes. Quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Well when you write 15+15/2, the interpretation is $15+\dfrac{15}{2}$. You need brackets to solve this ambiguity: $\dfrac{(15+15)}{2}$